# Docker container can not fetch configuration from bitbucket

Tags: git, spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a `EurekaService` and a `CloudConfigService` (I have other 3 services; but let's focus on the CloudConfigService).

`CloudConfigService` looks like this -

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudConfigServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudConfigServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`application.yml` -

```
server:
  port: 9296

spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://erfan_ahmed@bitbucket.org/erfan_ahmed/config-server-erfan.git
          clone-on-start: true
          default-label: master
```

This is how the `application.yml` of `../config-server-erfan.git` looks like -

```
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://eureka:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: eureka
```

`Dockerfile`-

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
#ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY /build/libs/cloud-config-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

After building image out of it, when I run the container using following command -

```
docker run -d --name cloud -p 9296:9296 --network my-network cloud
```

I get the following error -

> c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Instead of hitting `http://eureka:8761/eureka/`, `CloudConfig` always send get request to `localhost:8761`. Thus causing the error.

### Update 1

I found out that, from inside the container `CloudConfig` can not fetch config form git - `https://erfan_ahmed@bitbucket.org/erfan_ahmed/config-server-erfan.git`. That's why it falls back to default `localhost`.

I put the config from git into the `application.yml` file and it works.

So, why it can't fetch config from git url?

Comment: Are you expecting the config server to load it's configuration from git by default?

Comment: @spencergibb yes. It loads config from git while running from localhost.

Comment: See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__embedding_the_config_server.html and the bootstrap property

Comment: config server was built to get config from git, there should be some error there too

Comment: does git need to be installed in the container to fetch config from `https://erfan_ahmed@bitbucket.org/erfan_ahmed/config-server-erfan.git` ?

Comment: update: I've added git int the `Dockerfile` but the issue remains

Comment: the git cli is not used by spring cloud